# Delete entries from a list of dictionaries if a key includes a string from a list of strings

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries and each follows the exact same format. I have both a list of strings that indicate the dictionary should be kept and a list of strings that indicate the dictionary should be deleted. Something like:

```
d = [{"key1": 'x', "key2": 'y'},
     {"key1": 'x2', "key2": 'y2'},
     {"key1": 'x3', "key2": 'y3'}]
```

And if my list of strings to remove was

```
i = ['y2', 'y3']
```

The final list would be

```
d = [{"key1": 'x', "key2": 'y'}]
```

I know it should be some sort of dictionary comprehension and have tried

```
new_list = [a['key2'] for a in d if not any(j in a for j in i)]
```

As mentioned I also have a list of strings to keep if that would be more efficient.

Comment: `j in a` compares them to the keys in the dict. `j in a.values()` works as you expect. Also, single letter variable names are not generally a good idea :)

Comment: Should the dicts be removed if *any* of the values is "y2" or "y3", or should only those dicts whose `key2` is "y2" or "y3" be removed? In other words, if `i = ['x']`, would the first dict be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is actually simpler than your current attempt:

```
d = [{"key1": 'x', "key2": 'y'},
 {"key1": 'x2', "key2": 'y2'},
 {"key1": 'x3', "key2": 'y3'}]

i = ['y2', 'y3']
new_d = [c for c in d if c['key2'] not in i]
```

Output:

```
[{'key2': 'y', 'key1': 'x'}]
```